# How to compute the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(x) e^{A \sin (a x + t) \cos (2 x)}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I calculate the below integral?

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(x) e^{A \sin (a x + t) \cos (2 x)}\,\mathrm dx$$

$A$ and $t$ are constants.

Comment: a constant @MaximilianJanisch

Comment: There is no point in that! I removed it

Comment: it can be positive or negative @MaximilianJanisch

Comment: Nothing indeed! removed! @MaximilianJanisch